# Docker Pull - connection reset by peer

Tags: linux, docker, pull, proxmox

I use docker on a RockyLinux 8 LXC-Container on Proxmox 7-Host for a while and was able to pull images. For a few months now i am no more able to pull images from docker. The error message i get is:

```
Error response from daemon: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/hello-world/manifests/latest": read tcp 192.168.178.82:50660->18.209.128.237:443: read: connection reset by peer
```

I am not behind a proxy. The configuration worked fine in the beginning and i can't figure out what has changed since then. I have another instance of RockyLinux8 with docker on my Win10 using Hyper V. There i can pull images. I then tried to create another LXC with Ubuntu on my Proxmox and tried to run docker on there. I get the same error on ubuntu. So i tried to use an Ubuntu VM instead of LXC on my Proxmox, but still the same error. I guess there is something going wrong on my Proxmox server.

When i curl https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/hello-world/manifests/latest, this is the response:

```
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":[{"Type":"repository","Class":"","Name":"library/hello-world","Action":"pull"}]}]}
```

docker login is working and i tried it several times to login and logout again. I searched everything i found related to this error, but found no solution.

Comment: backup your "~/.docker/config.json" and delete it. Now try to do "docker login" to authentication and it should recreate that config.json file and should fix it

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the Bearer token first with :

```
curl -sS --user "docker_user:password" "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:library/hello-world:pull"
```

then using $token in :

```
curl -sS --header "Authorization: bearer $token" "https://index.docker.io/v2/library/hello-world/manifests/latest"
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't fix it. The first curl generated a token, but the second curl gave me the exact same error as before:

{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":[{"Type":"repository","Class":"","Name":"library/hello-world","Action":"pull"}]}]}

If i change "$token" with the actual token which was generated by the first curl, this is what i get:

curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 104

Comment: Are you sure you are fetching this : `https://index.docker.io/v2/library/hello-world/manifests/latest` ?